# How to open a web terminal in DataBricks platform running with a cluster with Custom Docker Image

Tags: docker, databricks

Before adding a Custom docker image, the cluster have this `open web terminal` in **apps** working just fine. But after I added a custom docker image to this cluster I got the message as shown below:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYpT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might need to activate it still in admin settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/clusters/web-terminal